# R diff() and 0 values

Tags: r, diff

I want to use `diff(log(myvar))` to calculate some time-series log returns. Some of the values in `myvar` are set to `0` and `diff()` returns `Inf` in this case, as it should mathematically.

How can I force `diff()` to make an exception and return `0` when either data point of the lagged pair is `0`? For example

```
diff(log(c(0,1,2,3,4)))
```

Would return

```
0 0.6931472 0.4054651 0.2876821
```

Forcing the very first calculated value to be `0` rather than `Inf`.

**UPDATE**
I actually had a problem using is.infinite(). Consider the following case:

```
> v = diff(log(c(1, 0, 0, 2, 3)))
> v 
[1]      -Inf       NaN       Inf 0.4054651
> is.infinite(v) 
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Here we have 3 different cases, -Inf, Inf and NaN. The goal is set 0 to all returns whose base quotation is 0 so I had to add `v[is.nan(v)] = 0`.

Why would I want to set returns to 0 rather than NA? Well this is more of a logical problem rather than a programming question, but the idea is that in my case 0 means that the reference price hasn't changed (and not that it is unknown).

Comment: What does a price of zero mean?  I would think that putting NA where there are zero prices and then doing the computations would be a safe way of proceeding.  Then you could distinguish between a return that was truly zero and something weird.

Comment: If returns are based on trades and there are no trades for that period the return is 0. If I use NA instead of 0 correlation functions would discard the observation.

Comment: Then I'm suspicious that computation you are doing gives you returns.  What are the non-zero values?  You want the value of the portfolio at each time point (including the cash that supports it) in order to get returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
d[is.infinite(d)] <- 0
```

Comment: abs(d) == Inf was giving me some errors because a few values are NA and I want to keep them. is.infinite is quite smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason the boneheaded solution of

```
d <- diff(log(x))
d[abs(d)==Inf] <- 0
```

doesn't work?  (Assuming you only have non-finite values in your data to begin with, I think the only way you can get `Inf` or `-Inf` is to have a zero value ...)

Comment: If there really isn't a way to do it in one pass I'll take this as the final answer. And yes, the only reason I end up with Inf is because for some periods my values == 0. btw, isn't this a very common problem in asset returns time-series analysis?

Comment: @RobertKubrick -- Do you need something faster than this? If not, I'd say don't sweat the extra line of code, since the second line (especially with `d[is.infinite(d)] <- 0`) should be **blazing** fast!

Comment: If you want to avoid an extra line, and you are confident that you know the precision and range of your data, then do `diff(log(my_data+1e-7))` or a similar trick to ensure all values are positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

Should also add

```
d[is.nan(d)] = 0
```

for 0/0 case.